# Charisma Mod to AC?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, armor-class

Is there a way to get your Charisma Modifier to AC other than different revelations* for oracles?  I've been looking through the content on the PFSRD and can't find one.  I'm hoping there might be something somewhere that couldn't make it to the PFSRD site.

Particularly interested in methods that can be used/obtained at low levels.

*listed are the revelations I know of

- *Sidestep Secret* revelation in the [Lore Mystery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/mysteries/paizo---oracle-mysteries/lore)
- *Prophetic Armor* revelation in the [Lunar Mystery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/mysteries/paizo---oracle-mysteries/lunar-mystery)
- *Nature's Whisper* revelation in the [Nature Mystery](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/mysteries/paizo---oracle-mysteries/nature)

Comment: This seems like a 'generate a list' type of question, which to me seems overly broad. Any way you can supply more information about your specific situation?

Comment: The thing is, that is my specific question.  I'm looking for ways to get Cha Mod to AC not just for one character but at least two, possibly more in the future.  There isn't an up-to-date "X Stat to Y Bonus" type of thing around and thus far I've listed the only solutions I know about.

Answer (score 5):

[Osyluth Guile](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/osyluth-guile-combat) is a feat that allows you to do this, albeit only against melee attacks from one opponent. And only when fighting defensively or on total defense.

Other than that, you could take a level in [Enlightened Paladin](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin/archetypes/paizo---paladin-archetypes/enlightened-paladin-paladin-archetype) (for Confident Defense) or Swashbuckler (for [Dodging Panache](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/swashbuckler#TOC-Deeds)). Or even a level in the third-party cleric archetype [Enthusiast](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/cleric/archetypes/kobold-press/enthusiast)?

Finally, the feat Demonic Obedience (Mestama) allows you to increase your age category by one, or become a ghost (which gains Charisma as a deflection bonus to AC, among numerous other benefits) if already venerable.

Answer (score 1):

#### Anyone can buy a *potion of [nereid's grace](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/n/nereid-s-grace)* (50 gp; 0 lbs.)

The 1st-level Drd spell *nereid's grace* for 1 round/level grants *either* an unarmored caster *or* a caster with inobvious armor—either of whom must touch himself (i.e. the spell's range isn't personal but a touch spell that can only target you)—, a deflection bonus equal to the subject's Charisma modifier to Armor Class and to CMD.

That the bonus is named and the duration so short is disappointing, though.

Comment: Technically, that spell (and therefore the potion) should only be made available to non-Undine characters with GM permission, right?

Comment: Although if the GM does allow it, you can make a magic item that gives you the spell's effect continuously for 8000 gp. 16,000 for a slotless item.

Comment: @shintsurugi Although that's the math, I can't see any DM allowing such a continuous item at a price below a *ring of protection +3* or *+4*, seeing as how a character with a Charisma bonus of less than 16 probably wouldn't bother with such an item.

Comment: @shintsurugi you cannot make a "spell effect" item when the effect is a numerical bonus. You have to follow the rules for numerical bonuses, and the spell becomes a requisite of the crafting.

Comment: (I suspect that the spell *nereid's grace* was updated by a printing of the *Advanced Race Guide* released after this answer was posted to change the spell's original entry of *Range: Touch* to its current entry of *Range: Personal.* For example, the first post of this [2013 thread](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2pxp9?Best-use-for-Nereid-Grace) copies the header information of the then-current version of the spell. This answer's suggestion doesn't work now as spells with an entry of *Range: Personal* can't be made into potions. Scrolls and especially psionic tattoos, however, are fair game.)